# Polymer scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, polymer

Long story short, I managed to put my paper-tab position fixed to the bottom. Tap anywhere and it will direct users to each core-animated-pages.

Everything works well when scrolling in Android. As soon as I tried it in iOS , the paper-tab gave me serious headache, when scrolling while touching it works quite okay, but when you swipe it, the paper-tab's position goes crazy, it follows the swiping (upwards or downwards) position and return to its original position after the scrolling stopped.

here is my css :

```
.menu-tab{position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
```

I put it in a wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
  }
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED].

made a fixed bottom div wrapper for the paper-tabs